# How to do multiple http POST request in one API endpoint using expressjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, express, rest

I'm trying to build `expressjs` API endpoint for AgileCRM. For my application purpose, I need to POST multiple requests in the same API endpoint and need to create an array[] and this array will wrap all of my AgileCRM user information

Also, I'm using `express 4+` which has `body-parser` included.

**First try**

```js
export const postSmsToTwilio = (request, response) => {
  let body = [];
  request.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', () => {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    response.end(body);
  });
}
```

**Second try**

```js
let users = []
try {
  let obj = req.body;
  users.push(obj);
}
catch (error) {
  res.status(500).send(error)
}
```

**Note:** Data comes from AgileCRM and it's `text/plain` or `application/json` format

#### My final objective is to show user information as shown below:

```js
[
  {
    "name": "As Md Habibullah",
    "phone": "+8615607860",
    "email": "asmdhabibah@yahoo.com",
    "car_brand": "Mercedes-Benz",
    "car_number": "256858"
  },
  {
    "name": "Filippo Masiero",
    "phone": "+39327738",
    "email": "asmdhablah@yahoo.com",
    "car_brand": "Mercedes-Benz",
    "car_number": "256458"
  },
  {
    "name": "Azad Ahmed",
    "phone": "+393477738",
    "email": "asmdhabibuh@yahoo.com",
    "car_brand": "Mercedes-Benz",
    "car_number": "26868"
  },
  {
    "name": "Md Musa",
    "phone": "+393477738",
    "email": "asmdhablah@yahoo.com",
    "car_brand": "Mercedes-Benz",
    "car_number": "2558"
  }
]
```

Is it possible? If so, please give me a suggestion on how can I do it.**
It will be my pleasure if you give me a suggestion.
Thanks @all

Answer (score 0):

An API accept 1 request by 1 request, you cant send multiple POST request and get 1 reponse.

You need to :

- Make multi request by your FrontEnd and wait all the result.

or

- Make 1 request we enought parameter to lets your back know what you want and return you the expected result (This is the proper solution)

EDIT :

Change that to make all your request :

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise/all

Comment: You are absolutely right. But Agile send data as a single object. this is the main problem.

Comment: Why is it a problem, do sync all your request, await each of them and combine all the result

Comment: No idea about it. How can I sync all the request and create one, have any implementation? If have please help me.

Comment: Use 'await Promise.all', check the doc, create a fucntion with your request parameter and  when all your request are done, you will have an array of the result, it's just an idea but you need to use Promise

Comment: You mean: const postSmsToTwilio = (request, response) =>
With this function I need to use async, await and promise also extra a function for resolve the all request?

Comment: Check my edited answer and change it to make request with an dynamic array with all your parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216283/discussion-between-as-md-habibullah-and-jonathan-delean).